# Actiontec Q1000 missing cp and rm from busybox

Tags: dsl, busybox

The new CenturyLink Q1000 busybox seems to be missing some crucial commands - namely rm, cp and ln.. It does have tftp so if I can, somehow find a server with binaries, I might be able to get those commands back. Does anybody know where I might find these?

There's a swversion command that returns: QAQ01-31.00L.34

H/W on physical box says: 1A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem burried deep in the comments section of this post: [here](http://blog.kgrothoff.org/2006/08/12/how-to-disable-the-actiontec-dsl-modem-web-activity-log).

Apparently, you have to type "sh" to get into the real BusyBox shell on this device. Once I did that, I got everything I needed.